# result expressions must have consistent types

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following terraform code that produces inconsistent types during terraform plan during an inline ternary with var.provision_capi_server_iam.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "aws_iam_role_controllers" {

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = flatten([
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          AWS = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/controllers.cluster-api-provider-aws.sigs.k8s.io"  
        }
      },
      var.provision_capi_server_iam ? [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          AWS = "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_id}:role/controllers.cluster-api-provider-aws.sigs.k8s.io"
        }
      },
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Federated = "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_id}:oidc-provider/${replace(data.aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster[0].identity[0].oidc[0].issuer, "https://", "")}"
        }
        Condition = {
          "ForAnyValue:StringEquals" = {
            "${replace(data.aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster[0].identity[0].oidc[0].issuer, "https://", "")}:sub" = [
              "system:serviceaccount:capa-system:capa-controller-manager",
              "system:serviceaccount:capi-system:capi-controller-manager",
              "system:serviceaccount:capa-eks-control-plane-system:capa-eks-control-plane-controller-manager",
              "system:serviceaccount:capa-eks-bootstrap-system:capa-eks-bootstrap-controller-manager",
            ]
          }
        }
      }
      ] : []

    ])
  })
```

Using terraform ver v0.14.8. I get this error on plan.

```
Using a variables file to set an undeclared variable is deprecated and will
become an error in a future release. If you wish to provide certain "global"
settings to all configurations in your organization, use TF_VAR_...
environment variables to set these instead.


Warning: Values for undeclared variables

In addition to the other similar warnings shown, 11 other variable(s) defined
without being declared.


Error: Inconsistent conditional result types

  on ../../../../../modules/capi-roles-and-policies/main.tf line 48, in resource "aws_iam_role" "aws_iam_role_controllers":
  48:       var.provision_capi_server_iam ? [
  49:       {
  50:         Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
  51:         Effect = "Allow"
  52:         Sid    = ""
  53:         Principal = {
  54:           AWS = "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_id}:role/controllers.cluster-api-provider-aws.sigs.k8s.io"
  55:         }
  56:       },
  57:       {
  58:         Action = "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
  59:         Effect = "Allow"
  60:         Sid    = ""
  61:         Principal = {
  62:           Federated = "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_id}:oidc-provider/${replace(data.aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster[0].identity[0].oidc[0].issuer, "https://", "")}"
  63:         }
  64:         Condition = {
  65:           "ForAnyValue:StringEquals" = {
  66:             "${replace(data.aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster[0].identity[0].oidc[0].issuer, "https://", "")}:sub" = [
  67:               "system:serviceaccount:capa-system:capa-controller-manager",
  68:               "system:serviceaccount:capi-system:capi-controller-manager",
  69:               "system:serviceaccount:capa-eks-control-plane-system:capa-eks-control-plane-controller-manager",
  70:               "system:serviceaccount:capa-eks-bootstrap-system:capa-eks-bootstrap-controller-manager",
  71:             ]
  72:           }
  73:         }
  74:       }
  75:       ] : []

The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given
expressions are tuple and tuple, respectively.
```

i tried changing [] to [{}] mentioned on line 75 error, but that doesn't seem to make a diff.

Please advise, any feedback is welcome.

Comment: I was able to fix this try replacing the ternary in line 48 above with a try function try(<my tuple above>, []). though i'm curious why the above didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is correct because the two result arms of your conditional expression have different types, and Terraform doesn't have enough information to guess what you intended.

The "true" result from your conditional expression effectively has the following type, since without any explicit type conversions Terraform must choose the most general interpretation of what you described:

```
tuple([
  object({
    Action = string
    Effect = string
    Sid    = String
    Principal = object({
      AWS = string
    })
  }),
  object({
    Action = string
    Effect = string
    Sid    = String
    Principal = object({
      Federated = string
    })
    Condition = object({
      "ForAnyValue:StringEquals" = object({
        "example.com:sub" = tuple([
          string,
          string,
          string,
          string,
        ])
      })
    })
  }),
])
```

The "false" result has the type `tuple([])` (empty tuple), though. Since tuple types are distinguished by their number of elements and the type of each element, Terraform doesn't understand your intention here.

Dynamic structures like IAM policy documents are unfortunately sometimes awkward to describe in Terraform's type system, because Terraform does not have a fully-dynamic type system and so expects to be able to resolve the result types for expressions independently of their values. This is in part why the `hashicorp/aws` provider offers [the `aws_iam_policy_document` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document), which has its own Terraform-friendly schema and then translates the input into an equivalent IAM policy document in JSON format. That allows Terraform to use the data source's configuration schema as extra information to assist with automatic type inference.

The `jsonencode` function does not imply any particular result type and so Terraform doesn't have anything other than the expression you wrote with which to infer the type you intended. Furthermore, the IAM policy document format is not directly describable purely as Terraform types, which is why `aws_iam_policy_document` uses a slightly different structure that fits better with Terraform's type system.

Here's an example of one way to describe this policy document using that data source:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example" {

  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }

  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/controllers.cluster-api-provider-aws.sigs.k8s.io"]
    }
  }

  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each = (
      var.provision_capi_server_iam ?
      tolist(["arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_id}:role/controllers.cluster-api-provider-aws.sigs.k8s.io"]) :
      tolist([])
    )
    content {
      actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

      principals {
        type        = "AWS"
        identifiers = [statement.value]
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each = (
      var.provision_capi_server_iam ?
      tolist([
        replace(data.aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster[0].identity[0].oidc[0].issuer, "https://", ""),
      ]) :
      tolist([])
    )
    content {
      actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

      principals {
        type        = "Federated"
        identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_id}:oidc-provider/${statement.value}"]
      }

      condition {
        test     = "ForAnyValue:StringEquals"
        variable = "${statement.value}:sub"
        values = [
          "system:serviceaccount:capa-system:capa-controller-manager",
          "system:serviceaccount:capi-system:capi-controller-manager",
          "system:serviceaccount:capa-eks-control-plane-system:capa-eks-control-plane-controller-manager",
          "system:serviceaccount:capa-eks-bootstrap-system:capa-eks-bootstrap-controller-manager",
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above is using [`dynamic` blocks](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) to make two of the four `statement` blocks conditional. In the second one, as a convenient side-effect this allows factoring out the non-trivial expression for extracting the hostname from the URL into the `for_each` expression, so that the two uses of it inside the block can be just `statement.value`.